# Removing duplicates indices from multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I received a `DataFrame` after using `pivot_table` which has some duplicate indices, like the following:

[image]

If you look at the second from the bottom entry, it has just 1 `memberid` for 2 `testscoreid`. There's a corresponding column in the `DataFrame` called `ScoreRatio` which I have not displayed here. I would only like to keep the `testscoreid` with the higher `ScoreRatio` value.

The data may be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B26EL85v1mxnX0p2WEh0OFpGbms/view?usp=sharing).

I tried using the following code but it didn't seem to have any affect:

```
selectedTestsPivotCorrect.reset_index(level=['memberid'])
selectedTestsPivotCorrect.groupby(selectedTestsPivotCorrect.index).last()
```

How do I do this for all the duplicate (or possible triples, quadruples etc) `memberid` present in my `DataFrame`?

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Next time post the data in text not in image.

Comment: @shivsn: Added the data file.